# How to transform images on server using Guillotine (JS) & Intervention

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I am using [Guillotine](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine) to let the user transform images. No instructions or examples are provided for how to actually apply the transformations on the server side. Using [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/), how do you do this properly?

The image is sent to the server with the following instructions:

```
{ scale: 1.4, angle: 270, x: 10, y: 20, w: 900, h: 675 }
```

So how to we take that info and apply it to the photo?

Here is what I have so far:

```
// Gets the true initial orientation
$img->orientate();

// Mirrors the image to what the user sees
$img->flip('v')->flip('h'); 

if(isset($fileData['angle']) && $fileData['angle'] > 0 && $fileData['angle'] < 360){
    $img->rotate($fileData['angle']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the GD library directly in PHP? That is what powers Intervention and for a simple task like this, it may be best to go straight to the source.

You can use the PHP GD library to resize, reshape, crop, etc. images
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

This script excerpt from an email signature creator will create a landscape image and position the user's profile picture on the left.

```
// Create image canvas (width, height)
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor(450, 74);

// Load image
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($img_path);

// Resize image and add to canvas
imagecopy($canvas, $img, 5, 5, 0, 0, 64, 64);

// Create image
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: The question has been updated in order to better reflect the desired tool to be used :)